# How to unsync branch from main

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab, branch

I have a problem with my Git branches in Intellij. I basically want to create a 'Testing' branch ['Testing' branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1lfu.png), but whenever I make changes to 'Testing' [Change to 'testing' branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAkRW.png), they appear on 'main' too [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N5VL.png).

Does it have to do something with rebasing? I spent a couple of hours and I do not seem to understand how to unsync. I've seen a lot of comments on how to sync, but not unsync.

Thank you very much.

I tried to rebase 'Testing' into  'main' but it did not work. I tried to create several branches to see if the changes made in other branches appear automatically in 'main'/

Comment: Did you *commit* you work? Until you commit, anything you're doing is not actually *in* Git. (Files in your working tree are not in Git. Think of the checkout or switch command as meaning *extract files from Git*, because it does in fact mean that. Until you `git add` and `git commit`, the extracted files are just sitting around after being extracted. It's the add-and-commit sequence that *puts them back* into Git, as a new revision.)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to share code as text, in code blocks. Avoid code as image. It is much harder to read and to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. While still in the branch, you must **git add** and **git commit**. This will add and commit your changes to that branch. You can now checkout main and it will not have the changes you committed to the branch.